# How to add DOM number function in ajax stocks datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, websocket

I am trying to create a live crypto currency price chart with jQuery, Javascript, Ajax and Websocket. Datatable is using for sorting purpose. Live crypto currency price is always appearing in `<input>`. It will always work outside of the datatable `<table>`. But if I put `<input>` in the datatable `<table>`, live price is not appearing. I searched in google and found the solution. DOM function needed to  getting live number value in datatable `<input>`. I am using this https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/stocks.html datatable for my project. I got DOM javascript code from https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html for live DOM  number sorting.

```
<script type="">
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-text-numeric'] = function (settings, col) {
    return this.api()
        .column(col, { order: 'index' })
        .nodes()
        .map(function (td, i) {
            return $('input', td).val() * 1;
        });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { orderDataType: 'dom-text-numeric' },
        ],
    });
});
</script>
```

These are the javascript code for live DOM soring. I don't know how/where put this codes in my Ajax javascript file.

**In the ajax javascript fie, I added,**

```
return type === 'display' ?
'<input type="text" id="btc-price" value="">' :
val;
```

So `<input>` is appearing in web page without live crypto price. I think DOM is missed in this datatable.
I tried many times. But all my efforts was failure.. Codepen preview: https://codepen.io/themecode/pen/VwxPOpJ  Please help me..

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sparklines/2.1.2/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- **************************************** -->
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Chnge</th>
        <th>Last</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Chnge</th>
        <th>Last</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
 <!-- **************************************** -->
<input type="text" id="btc-price" value="">
<input type="text" id="ltc-price" value="">
 <!-- **************************************** -->
<script type="text/javascript">
const streams =  {
  'btcusdt@trade': { name: 'btc', input: document.getElementById('btc-price') },
  'ltcusdt@trade': { name: 'ltc', input: document.getElementById('ltc-price') },
};
const streamParams = Object.entries(streams).map(([streamId]) => streamId).join(`/`);
const streamUrl = `wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=${streamParams}`;
const wss = new  WebSocket(streamUrl);
wss.onmessage = (event) => {
  const eventData = JSON.parse(event.data);
  const streamId = eventData.stream;
  const latestPrice = Number.parseFloat(eventData.data.p);
  const lastPrice = streams[streamId].lastPrice || latestPrice;
  // compare latest and last prices
  const inputClass = latestPrice > lastPrice
    ? 'inc'
    : latestPrice < lastPrice ?
      'dec' : '';
  // update relevant input with value 
  const input = streams[streamId].input;
  // remove any existing classes
  input.classList.remove('inc','dec');
  // add inc/dec class only
  if (inputClass)
    input.classList.add(inputClass);
  // set input value
  input.value = latestPrice.toFixed(2);
  // save the latest price for this coin.
  streams[streamId].lastPrice = latestPrice;
  // Call calculators.change() here - I can't actually add it because it will break the snippet.
  // calculators.change;
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var stock_data = [
        {
            "name": "ACME Gadgetsrrrrrrr",
            "symbol": "AGDTS",
            "last": [2, 9, 14, 18, 23, 27, 39]
        },
        {
            "name": "Spry Media Productions",
            "symbol": "SPMP",
            "last": [1.12, 1.11, 1.08, 1.08, 1.09, 1.11, 1.08]
        },
        {
            "name": "Widget Emporium",
            "symbol": "WDEMP",
            "last": [3.40, 3.39, 3.46, 3.51, 3.50, 3.48, 3.49]
        },
        {
            "name": "Sole Goodman",
            "symbol": "SGMAN",
            "last": [16.20, 16.40, 16.36, 16.35, 16.61, 16.46, 16.19]
        },
        {
            "name": "Stanler Bits and Bobs",
            "symbol": "SBIBO",
            "last": [82.51, 83.47, 83.40, 83.68, 83.81, 83.29, 83.72]
        }
    ];
 
    let table = $('#example').DataTable({
        ajax: function(dataSent, callback, settings) {
            let data = this.api().ajax.json();
            if(data == undefined) {
                data = stock_data; // ======================= data = stock_data;
            } else {
                data = data.data;
                for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    data[i].last.push(data[i].last.shift())
                }
            }
 
            callback({data: data});
        },
        paging: false,
        initComplete: function() {
            let api = this.api();
            setInterval(function() {
                api.ajax.reload();
            }, 3000);
        },
        drawCallback: function() {
            $('.sparkline')
                .map(function() {
                    return $('canvas', this).length ? null : this;
                })
                .sparkline('html', {
                    type: 'line',
                    width: '250px'
                })
        },
        columns: [
// ## 01 // Price
            { 
                data: null, // Price
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return row.last[row.last.length - 1].toFixed(2);
                }
            },
// ## 02 // Difference
             {
                data: null, // Difference
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    var val = (row.last[row.last.length - 1] - row.last[row.last.length - 2]).toFixed(2);
                    var colour = val < 0 ? 'red' : 'green'
return type === 'display' ?
'<input type="text" id="btc-price" value="">' :
val;
                }
            },
// ## 03 // Price
            {
                data: null, // Price
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return row.last[row.last.length - 1].toFixed(2);
                }
            },
// ## 04 // Difference              
            {
                data: null, // Difference
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    var val = (row.last[row.last.length - 1] - row.last[row.last.length - 2]).toFixed(2);
                    var colour = val < 0 ? 'red' : 'green'
                    return type === 'display' ?
                        '<span style="color:' + colour + '">' + val + '</span>' :
                        val;
                }
            },
// ## 05 // Price
            {
                data: null, // Price
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return row.last[row.last.length - 1].toFixed(2);
                }
            }           
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Another Ajax example : https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Comment: Hi , not sure exactly what is needed but you can assign value to input like this : `'<input type="text" id="btc-price" value="'+val+'">'` .